# Using scipy.integrate.ode to solve protoplanetary hydrostatic equilibria

Tags: python, scipy, physics, differential-equations

I have written code to solve the protoplanetary hydrostatic equilibria equations using first order euler method, and the results are as expected. I now want to rewrite it using fourth order Runge-Kutta solution, which is builtin to scipy.integrate.ode

[Expected result, attained by using a custom written euler method:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUaM5.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import ode


universalGasConstant = 8.31
gravitationalConstant = 6.67 * 10**-11
astronomicalUnit = 1.5 * (10**11)
coreMass = 5.9 * 10**24
sunMass = 2 * (10**30)
coreRadius = 0
coreDensity = 5500.0

semiMajorAxis = 5 * astronomicalUnit

gasMeanMolecularMass = 2.3 * 10**-3

coreRadius = (coreMass / ((4 / 3) * np.pi * coreDensity))**(1 / 3)
print('coreradius is', coreRadius)

hillSphere = (1**-4)*(semiMajorAxis) * (((coreMass) / (3 * sunMass))**(1 / 3))
print('hillsphere is', hillSphere)#THIS IS THE HILLSPHERE

numberOfSlices = 100000000 #NUMBER OF SLICES

deltaRadius = hillSphere / numberOfSlices
print('slice length is', deltaRadius)

#gravitationalForce = ((gravitationalConstant * coreMass) / 
    #(coreRadius + (deltaRadius)))


sunSurfaceTemperature = 5800
sunRadius = 6.96 * 10**8
equilibriumTemperature = sunSurfaceTemperature * \
    (sunRadius / (2 * semiMajorAxis))**(1 / 2)
print('equilibrium temperature at', semiMajorAxis,
      'metres is', equilibriumTemperature, 'kelvin')



pressureAtRadius = 0
initialDensity = 10.0 #INITIAL DENSITY
densityAtRadius = 0

muOverRT = gasMeanMolecularMass/(equilibriumTemperature * universalGasConstant)
print('muOverRT is', muOverRT)

totalMass = coreMass

densityAtRadius = initialDensity

def function(y, r):
        totalMass = y[0]
        distanceFromCOG = y[1]

        # the differential equations
        dRhodr = -(((gravitationalConstant*totalMass*
                       densityAtRadius*muOverRT))/(distanceFromCOG**2))
        dMdr = 4*np.pi*gravitationalConstant*densityAtRadius
        #dPdr = (1/(muOverRT))*dRhodr
        return [dRhodr, dMdr]


distanceFromCOG = coreRadius+np.linspace(0,numberOfSlices) #number of points
initialDensity = [0,0]       
solution = ode(function,initialDensity,distanceFromCOG).set_integrator('vode', method = 'dopri5')

plt.plot(solution)
solution.set_integrator('dopri5')
```

Comment: Error given: IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Comment: You have `initialDensity = [0,0]`, but `function(y, r)` returns `[dRhodr, dMdr, dPdr]`.  The lengths of those sequences must be the same.  The first gives the initial values  of your variables, and the second gives the rates of change (with respect to the independent variable) of your variables.

Comment: FYI: `odeint` is not a simple fourth order Runge-Kutta algorithm.  It is a wrapper of the Fortran LSODA library.

Comment: Rewriting using scipy.integrate.ode, will work on that for now

Comment: The result to the call of `ode` is an integrator object. There is more work to do than with the one-stop solution of `odeint`. Please read and utilize the documentation.

Comment: Im now working on adapting the code to properly use .ode, may take a while - i believe i have a long way to go. Meanwhile, I will keep the original post updated with developments. Thanks to everyone for their advice!